# While loop not working for array application

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have to write a small program where I have to cycle through the alphabet and make unique 4 character sets. So, my first set will be {ABCD), next will be {BCDE}, then {CDEF} and so on and so on. So I built a couple of nested while loops and a couple of arrays but my code won't run and I feel as dumb as a rock right now. Appreciate any help!!

```
int main()
{
    const int ALPHABET = 27;
    char array[ALPHABET] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0' };
    char set[4];
    int x = 0;
    int fact = 0;

    while (x >= 0 && x < 23);
    {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "{";
        while (i<=3) {
            set[i] = array[i];
            cout << set[i];
            i++;
        }
        cout << "}";
        x++;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semi-colon from the line `while (x >= 0 && x < 23);`.

You are also always accessing the same 4 elements of `array` in your loop, so you need to change the index variable too:

```
int main()
{
    const int ALPHABET = 27;
    char array[ALPHABET] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0' };
    char set[4];
    int x = 0;
    int fact = 0;

    while (x >= 0 && x < 23)
    {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "{";
        while (i<=3) {
            set[i] = array[x + i];
            cout << set[i];
            i++;
        }
        cout << "}";
        x++;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

You could also just use a `char` for `set` instead of an array, but it isn't an error this way either.